# What does landingpad do and when do i use it?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to figuring out what the `landingpad` instruction in LLVM IR exactly does and when to use it for exception handling purposes.
I can't find any other instruction, where `landingpad` has any usage like `catchpad` in combination with `catchswitch` and `catchret`.

Can someone give me a simple example how to use it? Thanks!

Comment: http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#landingpad-instruction